# Garbage collection after stopping threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, windows-7, garbage-collection

I have an app that runs around 400 threads simultaneously. Everything works fine. And the user is able to stop the threads by pressing some button.

To stop a thread, I have implemented a global variable that is set as `True` when the button is pressed.  The threads checks for this variable regularly. If ON, `return`.

`return` works fine for me as a way of stopping the thread: I can see no more output to the user from the threads.  However, when I check in the task manager memory I find the following:

- Before starting the threads, Python takes up around 64MB RAM
- After starting the threads, Python takes up around 700MB RAM
- After stopping the threads as above, Python
  takes around 600MB RAM but it never goes back to 64MB RAM

I think this is a garbage collection problem. Maybe using `return` is a bad idea. How can I solve this?

**Update:**

The App is a Tkinter App, and the threads runs in a separate TopLevel.

Comment: You mean *"After stopping the threads"* **AND** the app == main is still running?

Comment: yes, the (main) app is still running

Comment: *"yes, the (main) app is still running"*: Therfore all `global` or referenced objects still exists. You have to use `del <object>` to get the objects deleted. But keep in mind, objects which are referenced are still in memory. Read [how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, ´del´ didn't help much. So how can I delete objects which are refrenced in memory?

Comment: *"delete objects which are refrenced in memory?"*: Delete the reference also.

Comment: Relevant [Weak References in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9908216/7414759)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look