# How to delete an entry from a numpy array in place, and retain it's initial shape?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, in-place

Let's say, that we have a `numpy` array storing large objects. My goal is to delete one of these objects from memory, but retain the initial structure of the array. The cell, under which this object was stored might be filled for example with `None`.

Example simplified behaviour, where I replaced large objects with characters:

```
arr = numpy.asarray(['a', 'b', 'c']) # arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
delete_in_place(arr, 0)              # arr = [None, 'b', 'c']
```

I can't do this by calling `numpy.delete()`, because it will just return a new array without one element, which will take additional space in memory. This will also change the shape (by getting rid of given index), which I want to avoid.

My other idea was to just set `arr[0] = None` and call the garbage collector, but I'm not sure what the exact behaviour of such procedure would be.

Do you have any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Whats your end objective?  _"premature optimization is the root of all evil"_

Comment: What do you mean by large objects?  In your example, the elements are strings, and the resulting `dtype` will be 'U1'.  If you try that `None` assignment you'll get 'N' in that cell.  If it is an `object` dtype array, then the `None` can replace the referenced objects.  If those objects are not longer referenced, then yes, they will be garbage.

Comment: @tijko In general my array is a 2D one. I'm combining objects stored at different indices, and sometimes I want to store the result of such "combination" in place of one of the old objects, while the second one might be removed from the memory. I want to retain the structure of the array, so that I can properly handle the indices.

Comment: @hpaulj My objects can take several GB of memory and I just replaced them with simple strings for the purpose of the example.

Comment: As I pointed out, simple strings are stored in arrays differently.  You don't need to give us GB objects, but you still need to capture the core of the issue in your example(s).

Comment: Object dtype arrays are nearly the same as lists - containing references to objects stored elsewhere in memory.  They lack list methods like `append`, but provide basic array operations like `reshape` and 2d indexing.  Use them with caution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a `numpy` array, it has a fixed size. Eventually, when you try to delete an element it will create a new `numpy` array.

The way you are trying to do it, that's not an effective way. Please try another library.

Comment: Can this be achieved for example with basic python's lists?

Comment: @brzepkowski absolutely but as far as memory access you'd have to dive into the C-API

Comment: @tijko well said. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a multi-dimensional array and not even get `pandas` or `numpy` involved.  You will need the assistance of the `gc` module and builtin `del` command but thats the extent of things.

For example:

```
import gc

with open('large-dataset.txt') as fh:
    raw_data = fh.readlines()

# parse or object creation what-not
large_objs_multidim = [obj_create(i) for i in raw_data]
...
# No longer need a reference to large object
temp_obj = large_objs_multidim[0][0]
large_objs_multidim[0][0] = None
del temp_obj
# Python doesn't make guarantees about collection read up on ref-counts.
gc.collect()
```

This gives the general idea on how you need to invoke the garbage collector yourself.  There are some nuisances to Python's reference counting and objects in memory.  I don't know the intricacies to your project and code but you might benefit from reading into `__weakref__` too...

Also these link for further reading:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316793/1230086

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9908216/1230086

https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html